# Is Shimano Deore M5100 Rear derailleur compatible with Shimano 105 11-speed groupset?

Tags: cassette, derailleur-rear, shifting

I have a road bike equipped with full Shimano 105 11-speed groupset from top to bottom. The current rear derailleur is RD-5800. Is it ok to replace it with a Deore M5100 Rear derailleur, which is also 11-speed? I only plan to use it as a road bike, maybe some easy gravel ride too. I have a 11-28 teeth cassette. Maybe I will also swap that with 11-30 cassette. Is there anything I need to look out for?

Answer (score 5):

It's not compatible: MTB and road products above 10 speeds have different pull-ratios (ratio between cable movement derailleur displacement), and also because the Deore is designed to be paired with cassettes much larger than cassettes typically found on road bikes.

If your goal is to fit a larger cassette: the medium cage version of the RD-R5800 is compatible with 11/32. The short cage version is however limited to 11/28 cassettes.

The largest cassette that would be compatible is 11/34, with a GRX derailleur (RD-RX810) or a 105 RD-R7000-GS (that is now discontinued, so availability is less guaranteed), but I would only go in that direction if you have the short cage version and need this capability, or if your your rear derailleur is broken. The gain compared to what a medium cage can support is marginal.

You'll also need a slightly longer chain if you install a larger cassette (2 links longer from 11/28 to 11/32).

Comment: The RD-R7000 105 derailleur also handles 34t in the GS version, no need to use GRX.

Comment: Actually, the GS version of the 5800 Rd is likely to handle an 11-34. I am doing this with a 6800 GS RD.

Comment: @Noise Good point. I actually hesitated to mention it because it has been recently discontinued. But it's true it can be still found, and on the second hand market.

Comment: @Renaud I expect it will be available for a while as current model bikes are shipping with it and Shimano will support existing systems for some years. The electronic/di2 105 has been announced but is not yet actually available to order, meaning R7000 is the current product.

Comment: @Noise Agree, and that's why I edited the answer. Eternal problem of "shopping questions"...

Comment: Thanks @Renaud and everyone. One correction: according to Shimano, event the SS verison of RD-R7000 can handle max 11-30 teeth. https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/RD-R7000-SS.html

Comment: With a Shimano road 11 speed shifter, there is a device that can alter the pull that the rear derailleur sees, in order to use a MTB derailleur with road shifters.  Wolf Tooth makes a product called Tanpan that does this.  There may be other besides this.  https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/tanpan  I used one of these successfully with Shimano Ultegra 8000 series shifters/brifters and a corresponding 11 speed XT MTB derailleur to run an 11-40 11-speed rear cassette without issue.